# IE10 - Hover makes image itself flicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, hover

This problem only appears in IE, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

[www.british-nannies.uphero.com](http://www.british-nannies.uphero.com)

Whenever one of the counties is hovered over, the image flickers. This only happens in IE, and I can't figure out why.

I used jQuery for the tags:

```
$('#surrey').hover(function(){
                $('#surreyTag').css({'visibility':'visible'});   
            },function(){
                $('#surreyTag').css({'visibility':'hidden'});      
                });
```

and CSS for the color change:

```
 #hampshire{
            background:url("Imgs/hampshire.png");
            width:209px;
            height:192px;
            margin-top:-163px;
            margin-left:79px;
        }
       /*-----COUNTY HOVER INTERACTIVITY----*/ 
        #hampshire:hover{background:url('Imgs/hampshireSelected.png');}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It happens because the new image has to load. Preloading or a sprite is the answer.

Comment: Instead of visibility, maybe switch display? none/block?

Comment: What version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: Adeneo - I've added a preloader, http://jsfiddle.net/bVEHx/, it still happens.

Comment: Liam - I'm using the latest version of jQuery

Comment: That's because you're hovering over the tooltip thing. And by the way, I get this in IE 10: `HTML1506: Unexpected token. www.british-nannies.uphero.com, line 93 character 1` - why is there a `<script>` outside of `<html></html>`?

Comment: Melancia - Didn't work :( Ian - I don't have script tags outside my HTML anywhere.

Comment: @DanLevings You do, but it's not your fault. They seem to be inserted by your hoster. Check your page source and you'll see them at the bottom

Answer (score 3):

You rely on `pointer-events: none`, which is [not supported](http://caniuse.com/pointer-events) in IE10 (for HTML elements, at least).

If you remove `pointer-events: none`, you'll find that all browsers have the same problem.

Comment: Nice catch, I was wondering why it wouldn't flicker in other browsers; I didn't think that `pointer-events` would be used

Comment: Here is a demo with `pointer-events: none` commented out in the CSS, if anybody would like to assist OP and find a fix: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/2patD/

Comment: I see, so I need to look for a work-around for IE. Thanks alot! :) Any ideas on how I can do this?

Comment: I think the only "fixes" I can think of is with either a delay for the `mouseleave` (to see if the user has hovered on its associated "tooltip"), or use a `<map>`